# this._waiting is undefined

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper class for web workers. When one of the defined messages is sent to the webworker, the LayoutBridge assigns a ticket, that is returned when the request has been processed. This way, I should be able to run callbacks for these requests.

I get the following error

> TypeError: this._waiting is undefined

in _recvMsg.

Here's the code, I've been trying to solve this self made riddle for a couple of days now, but can't see what I'm doing wrong, as waiting is defined in both the LayoutBridge constructor and (just to make sure) in the init function.

I'll post a jsfiddle immediately after this, but maybe someone knows the answer already.

```
var LayoutBridge = function(){

    this._waiting = {};
    this._initialized = false;

};

LayoutBridge.prototype.init = function(opts){
    if(!this._initialized){
        this._waiting = {};

        this._worker = new Worker('/layout-worker.js');
        this._worker.onmessage = this._recvMsg;
        var ticket = _.uniqueId();

        var waitingCallback = function(){
            this._initiated = true;
        };
        waitingCallback.bind(this);
        this._waiting[ticket] = waitingCallback;

        this._worker.postMessage({cmd: 'init', ticket: ticket});
        this._initialized = true;
    }
};

LayoutBridge.prototype.addVertex = function(callback){
    if(!this._initialized) throw "Initialize LayoutBridge first";

    var ticket = _.uniqueId();
    this._waiting[ticket] = callback;
    this._worker.postMessage({cmd: 'addVertex', ticket: ticket});
};

LayoutBridge.prototype.removeVertex = function(id, callback){
    if(!this._initialized) throw "Initialize LayoutBridge first";

    var ticket = _.uniqueId();
    this._waiting[ticket] = callback;
    this._worker.postMessage({cmd: 'removeVertex', id: id, ticket: ticket});
};

LayoutBridge.prototype.addEdge = function(sourceId, targetId, callback){
    if(!this._initialized) throw "Initialize LayoutBridge first";

    var ticket = _.uniqueId();
    this._waiting[ticket] = callback;
    this._worker.postMessage({cmd: 'addEdge', sourceId: sourceId, targetId: targetId});
};

LayoutBridge.prototype._recvMsg = function(e){
    this._waiting[e.data.ticket](e.data.payload);
    //delete this._waiting[e.data.ticket];
};
```

Edit, here's the fiddle: suggestion included: http://jsfiddle.net/MGSvj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning your function to another class changes its scope.

Here you are assigning your this._recvMsg function to the Worker class.

```
this._worker.onmessage = this._recvMsg;
```

Hence in the code here, **this** will be either the window object or the worker object (not too sure about it but it definitely wont be the LayoutBridge object).

```
LayoutBridge.prototype._recvMsg = function(e){
    this._waiting[e.data.ticket](e.data.payload);
    //delete this._waiting[e.data.ticket];
};
```

To fix this, All you need to do is

```
var oThis = this;
this._worker.onmessage = function (){ oThis._recvMsg };
```

Also, as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Blob

Blob requires an array as a parameter.

So your code

```
var blob = new Blob($('#layout-worker').html());
```

should be

```
var blob = new Blob([$('#layout-worker').html()]);
```

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error. Do you have general advice for debugging web workers? (I know this particular error wouldn't have been caught by much I could do) Maybe you have some general words of wisdom...

Comment: chrome provides a good debugging tool. Just type 'debugger;' in the code where you are getting the error. And while running your code, keep the chrome console open (press F12). And your code will stop there and you can easily figure out what went wrong step by step.

Comment: Well, it got rid of the error, but the callbacks still aren't called. I used `var oThis = this; this._worker.onmessage = function(e){oThis._recvMsg(e); };`

Comment: It's a underscore.js function. Sorry for the omission. will edit for posterity